# roswtf and rpath problems in fuerte

Tags: ros, manifest.xml, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently noticed that running `roswtf` on every package that I have produces errors related to rpath and the linker.  For example, following the tutorial on creating ros packages [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) you create a new package by running the command

```
roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

Then if I `cd` to the `beginner-tutorials` directory, and run `roswtf`, I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
Package: beginner_tutorials
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
* beginner_tutorials: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* std_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* roscpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
```

The question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10246/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-rpath-in-manifestxml/) seems to indicate that I should not be using `-L` commands within the export tag.  I don't have any references to export or cpp in any of the manifests that produce these errors.

Basically every package I have written produces these same errors.  What is causing this?  What else should I be including in my manifest.xml?

**EDIT**

Adding the following line to the manifest (per manifest documentation) does not improve anything:

```
<export>
  <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -lros"/>
</export>
```

Explicitly specifying the `-rpath` directory using

```
-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib
```

Removes the error for the beginner_tutorials package. But I am still getting errors for `std_msgs`, and `roscpp`. Is there a bug in roswtf? Should there be something else in the manifests for these packages?

Clearly, this isn't causing much of a real problem, but the "ERROR" note is definitely unsettling.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38026/roswtf-and-rpath-problems-in-fuerte/) by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9031 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-07-17**:
Note, I just found [this link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/1758) from ros-users that explains `-rpath` and `-Wl` very well.  Although, my question still stands, is there a problem with `roswtf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe [this documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html#export-cpp) will help.

EDIT: The export changes need to be made in the `beginner_tutorials`, `std_msgs` and `roscpp` packages.

To get that fixed, someone needs to open defect tickets for those packages.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-07-17**:
Created a ticket [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4012).  Thanks for the help!